# solaris boot from cdrom fails on OBP

Tags: solaris-10

I am having following problem when I try to boot cdrom on OBP.
Google didnt tell me so much.
Do you have any idea?

```
{0} ok boot /pci@7c0/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/ide@8/cdrom
Boot device: /pci@7c0/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/ide@8/cdrom  File and args:
WARNING: max-cpus property missing from MD platform node, using default NCPU value
SunOS Release 5.10 Version Generic_147147-26 64-bit
Copyright (c) 1983, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
WARNING: Last shutdown is later than time on time-of-day chip; check date.
panic: failed to stop cpu12
panic: failed to stop cpu13
panic: failed to stop cpu14
panic: failed to stop cpu15
panic: failed to stop cpu20
panic: failed to stop cpu21
panic: failed to stop cpu22
panic: failed to stop cpu23

panic[cpu1]/thread=2a10048fc80: xt_sync: timeout

000002a10048eb40 unix:xt_sync+374 (2a10048ecb8, 1, 2a10048ec98, cce36706ec, 1, 19ddc28)
  %l0-3: 0000000000000008 000000cce366d998 000000cd2aed9314 000000cd2aed92ec
  %l4-7: 000002a10048eca0 0000000000000020 0000000000000000 00000000010c5c98
000002a10048f0a0 unix:hat_unload_callback+7d4 (7fc00, 2a10048f2b8, 0, 2a10048f3b8, 0, 300056db480)
  %l0-3: 000000007b79c000 fffffffffffffff8 0000000000000001 0000000000000001
  %l4-7: 0000000000000000 000003000e5ef008 ffffffffffffffff 00000300056db488
000002a10048f500 unix:segkmem_free_vn+58 (1a5a3d8, 7b750000, 4c000, 1a6f230, 30000000000, 26)
  %l0-3: 0000000000001c00 0000000000000000 0000060023394f88 0000000001911320
  %l4-7: 0000030005153000 00000000010c9800 0000000000000000 0000000001a71400
000002a10048f5b0 unix:free_module_data+29c (60024362f00, 1a7a400, 0, 19dd400, 1a71400, 1a7a400)
  %l0-3: 000000000000000a 0000000000000000 0000060023394f88 0000000001911320
  %l4-7: 0000030005153000 00000000707f5fc0 0000000000000000 0000000001a71400
000002a10048f660 genunix:mod_unload+9c (60024135a70, 60024135a70, 0, 60024135a70, 0, 0)
  %l0-3: 000000000000000a 0000000000000000 0000060023394f88 0000000000008b90
  %l4-7: 0000030005153000 00000000000009f8 0000000000000001 0000000001a7a000
000002a10048f710 genunix:mod_hold_installed_mod+b0 (60023394f88, 0, 0, 2a10048f87c, 1, 60024135a70)
  %l0-3: 000000000000000a 0000000000000000 0000060023394f88 0000000000008b90
  %l4-7: 0000030005153000 00000000000009f8 0000000000000001 0000000001a7a000
000002a10048f7c0 genunix:modrload+100 (1a29dd8, ffffffffffffffff, 0, 13f, 16, 3)
  %l0-3: 000000000000000a 0000000000000000 0000060023394f88 0000000000008b90
  %l4-7: 0000030005153000 00000000000009f8 000000000000013f 0000000000000001
000002a10048f880 genunix:mod_hold_dev_by_major+bc (0, 1a7b000, 1a29dd8, 1a7d648, 8b90, 1a26070)
  %l0-3: 00000300051539f8 000000000000013f 0000000001a19040 0000000000008b90
  %l4-7: 0000030005153000 00000000000009f8 000000000000013f 0000000000000001
000002a10048f930 genunix:ddi_hold_installed_driver+4 (13f, 2a10048fc80, 89d, 1, 70178098, 3000532a9e8)
  %l0-3: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000008b90 0000000001a720e0
  %l4-7: 0000000001a7d648 0000000000000101 000003000532ab90 0000030005322000
000002a10048f9e0 genunix:attach_drivers+44 (13f, 160, 0, 1a7d400, 1a72000, 160)
  %l0-3: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000008b90 0000000001a720e0
  %l4-7: 0000000001a7d648 0000000000000101 000003000532ab90 0000030005322000

syncing file systems... done
skipping system dump - no dump device configured
rebooting...
```

Answer (score 1):

What does "date" give you when you try it from the OK prompt? Also, as long as the system is down- have you tried replacing the battery to have the date in OBP reset? Solaris has been known not to properly boot if the OBP's time is off by a lot. Oracle is going to ask you to patch your system, as usual. There's a [bug](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?_afrLoop=146910353625804&id=15746515&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=13w84hblu0_60) in [Patch ID 1365975.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/ui/km/SearchDocDisplay.jspx?returnToSrId=&srnum=&_afrLoop=146857409761607&type=DOCUMENT&id=1365975.1&displayIndex=1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=13w84hblu0_39) talking about an xt sync issue on low end T series servers, you might want to check that out.

From Oracle's site-

----------- Migrated Description from BugTraq ------------
System panics with xt_sync: timeout

PLATFORM ?
Appears to be specific to sun4v
Seen examples on T2000 and now new one on T1000

WHAT CHANGED ?
Issue correlates with application of patch 147440-02 or 147440-03

WORKAROUND ?
This bug can be mitigated by updating the system's firmware to 6.4.6 or 
greater.

Comment: Half of this should be a comment, try to reformat this answer a bit and provide some hyperlinks to the bugs and patches you refer.